# How to control charging cycle on Windows?

Tags: windows, battery

I was wondering if there was an application that would manage charging cycles of my notebook.
I mean it would discharge from 100% do like 10% and then start charging to 100%.
It would be good for my battery.

Regards.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here, but you can reword your question to explain the problem you are having and ask how to overcome it. Remember to include anything you've already tried or researched. This would help prevent your question being closed.

Comment: The laptop OEM normally provides this sort of software.  There isn't a universal software suite for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not good* for the battery. Your notebook is not using NiMH or NiCd batteries. It is most likely using a **Li-Ion** battery. The most important fact is that it **must not, ever** be **completely discharged** (0%). This will deal great damage to your battery and can lead to loss of up to 20% capacity at a time.

There's a [great article](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2011/02/ask-ars-what-is-the-best-way-to-use-an-li-ion-battery/) on this topic on Ars Technica. I'll quote some key points:

On **memory effect**:

> There used to be certain types of batteries whose "memory" of their total charge capacity seemed to get confused by shallow discharges. This is not, and never was, the case with Li-ion batteries.

About **charge cycles**:

> [...] Li-ion batteries actually count charge cycles based on a 100 percent discharge even when it's summed over multiple sessions. For example, if you discharge a battery to 50 percent one day, charge it back to 100 percent, then discharge it 50 percent again the next day, that is counted as one "cycle" of the battery. So shallow discharges, in all these regards, are ideal for a Li-ion battery.

About the only thing you can accomplish by discharging until your computer shuts down is recalibrating the battery gauge. That being said, the ThinkVantage Power Manager can do this. Other manufacturers may offer similar utilities. They are, however, wasting charge cycles.